# Verifying Green's function is propagator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, greens-functions, propagator

I'm studying about many body quantum physics following *'Introduction to quantum field theory in condensed matter physics'* (Bruus).
In section 7, it says that Green's function can be interpreted to propagator of wavefunction via:

$$\Psi(\vec{r},\vec{t}) = \int d\vec{r'} \int dt' G(\vec{r}t,\vec{r'}t') \Psi(\vec{r'},t').$$

I tried to insert this into Schrodinger equation to verify this: $[i\partial_t-H_0-V]\Psi(\vec{r},\vec{t})=0$

The definition of the full Green's function is given in the book : $[i\partial_t-H_0-V]G(\vec{r}t,\vec{r'}t')= \delta(\vec{r}-\vec{r'}) \delta(t-t')$

Hence these equations lead to :

$ [i\partial_t-H_0-V] \int d\vec{r'} \int dt' G(\vec{r}t,\vec{r'}t') \Psi(\vec{r'},\vec{t'}) = \int d\vec{r'} \int dt' [i\partial_t-H_0-V] G(\vec{r}t,\vec{r'}t') \Psi(\vec{r'},\vec{t'}) = 
\int d\vec{r'} \int dt' \delta(\vec{r}-\vec{r'}) \delta(t-t')\Psi(\vec{r'},\vec{t'})
= \Psi(\vec{r},\vec{t})$

which means it's not solution of Schrodinger equation. I'm very confused about this result and I really can't get where I made a mistake. Please let me know why it is wrong and what is the appropriate way to verify that Green's function is propagator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The expression in the text is
$$\Psi(\mathbf r,t) = \Psi^0(\mathbf r,t) + \int\mathrm d\mathbf r' \int \mathrm dt \ G(\mathbf r,\mathbf r';t,t) V(\mathbf r') \Psi^0(\mathbf r',t')\tag{7.17}$$
where $\Psi^0$ is a solution to $[i\partial_t - H_0]\Psi^0 = 0$.  It's not difficult to see that $[i\partial_t - H_0 - V]\Psi^0 = -V\Psi^0$, and that the application of $[i\partial_t-H_0-V]$ to the second term yields $V\Psi^0$.  As a result, $\Psi$ obeys the Schrodinger equation as promised.

Comment: I think you used Green's function "not including perturbation-like potential". I think it is slightly deviated from my question, but it helped my understanding. Thank you.

Comment: @momo The perturbation-like potential is $V$.

Comment: Oh, my question is about eq.7.21 in the textbook. Does it have different meaning comparing to the definition of Green's function defined above eq.7.14(b)?

Answer (score 4):

Starting from dimensional analysis point of view, something is off in your definitions. Your last equations implies $(i\partial_t - H)\psi = \psi$ which can't be right. To see where the issue is coming from we can go back to your starting point: in the first equation it seemed to be implied that $[G] = [r^{-3} t^{-1}]$, as integrating over space and time returns $\psi$ to itself. However from the definition of the GF you give it has dimensions of $[G] = [r^{-3}]$, as the left-hand-side has $[t^{-1}] [G]$ and the right hand side $[r^{-3} t^{-1}]$.

There are two issues here:

i)  this is not how the propagator in non-relativistic QM works. We propagate from point $x$ to $x'$ and from time $t'$ to $t$ by *multiplying* with $K(x, t ; x', t')$ so when we want to look at the evolution into $\psi(r, t)$ we integrate over all space **but not over time**
$$\psi(r, t) = \int \! dr K(r, t; r', t') \psi(r', t')$$
see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagator) under "Non-relativistic propagators".

ii) the GF is not purely the propagator but rather, the GF is related to the propagator $K$ by $G = - i\theta(t-t')K$ (this is the retarded GF. The advanced one is given by $G^a = i\theta(t'-t)K$). Again, I refer you to the wikipedia link above.

So using both these adjustments, when we want to check Schrödinger equation for GF we need to write
$$ -i\theta(t-t')(i\partial_t - H)\psi = -i\theta(t-t')(i\partial_t - H)\int \! dr K(r, t; r', t') \psi(r', t') = (i\partial_t - H) \left[-i \theta(t-t')\int \! dr K(r, t; r' t') \psi(r', t')\right] - \delta(t-t')\int \! dr K(r, t; r' t') \psi(r', t') \\ = (i\partial_t - H)\int\! dr G(r, t; r', t')\psi(r', t') -\delta(t-t')\psi(r, t) = \int \! dr \delta(r-r')\delta(t-t')\psi(r', t') \\ = \delta(t-t')\psi(r, t) - \delta(t-t')\psi(r, t) = 0$$
as required

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll carefully read your comment and documents attached.